# Rails: Two different NoMethodError's when trying to display files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a basic application and I made it so a user can attach a file to a form post. That all works perfectly fine, but now I'm trying to display a link to the file and it doesn't seem to work.

I'm getting two errors. One if I attach a file and another if I don't attach a file. They both say `undefined method 'doc=' for nil:NilClass` but are on different lines of code.

If I don't upload a file this is what I get: `NoMethodError in Projects#index` on this line of code `<% if @project.doc %>`.

If I do upload a file this is what I get: `NoMethodError in ProjectsController#create` on this line of code `@project.doc = uploaded_io.original_filename`

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @projects = Project.all
  end

  def show


  end

  def new
    @projects = Project.new

  end

  def create #no view
    @projects = Project.new(project_params)
    uploaded_io = params[:doc]
    if uploaded_io.present?
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
          file.write(uploaded_io.read)
          @project.doc = uploaded_io.original_filename
      end
    end
    if @projects.save
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project was sent!"
    else 
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def edit
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @projects.update_attributes(project_params)
      redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been updated."
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def destroy #no view
    @projects = Project.find(params[:id])
    @projects.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path, :notice => "Your project has been deleted."
  end

  private
  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description)
  end


end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Projects<small> Here are all of your projects.</small></h1>
  </div>
</div>

<% @projects.each do |project| %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
  <%= project.title %>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
  <p>
  <%= project.description %> 
  </p>
  <br>
  <%= link_to "Discuss", new_project_discussion_path(project) %> |
  <%= link_to "Tasks", new_project_task_path(project) %> |
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_project_path(project) %> |
  <%= link_to "Delete", project, :method => :delete %> 

  <% if @project.doc %>
    <p>Document: <%= link_to @project.doc, "/uploads/#{@project.doc}", :target => "_blank" %></p>
  <% end %>


  </div>
  </div>
<%end%>

<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/projects/new" role="button">Create project</a></p>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@projects, :html => { :multipart => true}) do |f| %>

  <% if @projects.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @projects.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>



  <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>

    <%= label_tag :doc, 'Files (optional)' %>
    <%= file_field_tag :doc %>

    <br>

    <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.submit "Submit Project", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try <%= project.doc %> without @, and see if that works.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated : 
You have many errors, here are a few that I found :

```
uploaded_io = params[:doc]
```

Should be

```
uploaded_io = params[:project][:doc]
```

Also delete this line

```
@project.doc = uploaded_io.original_filename
```

You don't need that.

Finally, in your views, you should have `project.doc` instead of `@project.doc`

Comment: I did this and no longer get an error when I don't attach a file, but if I do attach a file I'm still getting `undefined method 'doc=' for nil:NilClass` in my `ProjectsController#create` on this line here: `@project.doc = uploaded_io.original_filename`

Comment: What you are trying to do is completely wrong. Here is what I suggest : delete all of this :  if uploaded_io.present?
      File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
          file.write(uploaded_io.read)
          @project.doc = uploaded_io.original_filename
      end
    end, and in your views just use project.uploaded_io.original_filename instead of project.doc

Comment: Also consider upvoting answers if you want more help from people.

Comment: I did this and it fixed my errors which is good, except the file doesn't show up anywhere. It should say "Document: (link to file should be here)". And sorry I'm not sure what you mean by accepting answers? I haven't used stack much before. And I would like to upvote... But I need 15+ reputation before I can do so.

Comment: Below the upvote button, there is a correct sign, when you click it it will become green and the answerer will get points, that's what I mean by 'accepting answers'. You can accept answers that were helpful to you without needing reputations. To answer you question, try project.uploaded_io, without original_filename.

Comment: Hm so I did all that you said and it seems to be working (I assume) but there's still no link in my index.... In my index it displays the "project" I just made and below it has links to "Discuss, Tasks, Edit, Delete" as you can see... But I can't figure out why a link to the documents i'm uploading isn't showing up?

Comment: in your view, do you have project.doc or project.uploaded_io ?

Comment: it was `project.uploaded_io.original_filename` so I changed it to `project.doc.original_filename` just now and still nothing. I also tried just `project.doc` and nothing.